# Can I use function of class template return type?

Tags: c++, class, templates

Just want to ask simple question to you professions !
I implemented template class like code below :

```
template <typename T>
class Matrix { ... };
```

And I am trying to use function which has return type as class template.

```
Matrix<double> get_some_matrix(int param1,int param2) {...};
```

Unfortunately, compiler generates error message like : Error C2143 :  missing ';' before '<'

Can anyone tell me or guess what the problem is ?

I really appreciate your help, thank you so much !

Comment: Post a code before your `get_some_matrix` function. You've probably missed `;` after `Matrix` definition.

Comment: If that is the definition immediately prior to the function you have, then you need it to finish with `};`, not `}`.

Comment: What do you have just before that function definition?

Answer (score 5):

```
template <typename T>
class Matrix { ... } //missing ; at end of class declaration.
```

Should be:

```
template <typename T>
class Matrix { ... };  // note ;
```

Comment: Sorry. I already put ; to the declaration of class but i miss it in the post.

Comment: I think the source of error is not ; in end of class declaration. Do you think anything else for the source of error?

Answer (score 1):

If this is your exact declaration, you are missing a semicolon after the closing brace of the class declaration.

Comment: Thanks ! But as I comment in the above answer, do you think anything else for the source of error ?

Comment: Not in the code your posted, but I guess there is a lot of code you didn't post. Maybe you can complete your starting post.